# Insert into table is not working inside foreach Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, foreach, insert, laravel-5.8

I amtrying to insert values to laravel table inside a foreach. In my view I am selecting some checkboxes and I need its value to get inserted into a table. In my controller, I am getting all the required values to be inserted into the table. But everytime when I run, the code inside the foreach results in error.
Here is my controller code.

```
try {
        $e_id = request()->segment(3);
        $et = $repository->find($e_id);
        if (!empty($et)) {
            $rules = [
                's_users' => 'bail|required|array',
                'e_id' => 'bail|required',
            ];
            $messages = [
                's_users.required' => required,
                'e_id.required' => required ,
                's_users.array' => required,
            ];
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 1, 'code' => 422, 'errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
            } else {

                DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $admin) {
                    DB::table('e_users')->whereIn('user_id', $request->input('s_users'))->delete();

                    foreach ($request->input('s_users') as $suser) {
                     $eUsers = new EUsers();
                        $eUsers->e_id = $request->input('e_id');
                        $eUsers->uid = $suser;
                        $eUsers->save();

                    }
                   });
                return response()->json(['error' => 0, 'code' => 200, 'message' => "success"], 200);
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("invalid);
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 1, 'code' => 200, 'message' => "unknown error occurred"], 200);
    }
```

The above code always throws exception, which shows unknown error occured. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a syntax error there, is that a copy/paste error or your actual code?

Comment: You should get an actual error message, at least for debugging.. Use `$e->getMessage()`.

Comment: Thanks Qirel. Now I got the error. Its because a field was missing in Database.